# Convert JSONObject to JSONArray in Android JAVA?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to prepare JSON data for an ArrayAdapter to add to a listView.

A breakdown of the JSON I am digesting from a server is such:

```
{
"friends": {
            "mufasa3": "false",
            "jenkins": "false"
           }
}
```

I convert this JSON to a java JSONObject like:

```
try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonDigest);

                Object thelist = obj.get("friends");

                }

            }catch(JSONException e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

How do I convert `Object thelist` to an Array so that I can use it with a my custom ArrayAdapter?
I've tried `JSONArray arr = obj.toJSONArray("friends");` but errors because there is no existing array in the JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
  Object thelist = obj.get("friends");
```

> I've tried JSONArray arr = obj.toJSONArray("friends");

Why you using **toJSONArray** ? .**JSON ARRAY** is not present there.

**Do**

```
 JSONObject sys  = obj.getJSONObject("friends");
```

**Finally**

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonDigest);
JSONObject sys  = obj.getJSONObject("friends");
String str_MUFA = sys.getString("mufasa3");
String str_JENK = sys.getString("jenkins");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate though all the keys in JSONObject and add it to a list

```
List<String> friends=new ArrayList<>();

for(Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();iter.hasNext();) {
    String key = iter.next();
    friends.add(key);
    ...
}
```